Ubuntu 23.10.1 Freeze AMD Ryzen 5
I'm relatively new to Linux and I've been encountering quite a few issues while trying to navigate Ubuntu on my system. Despite having everything updated and upgraded, I'm still experiencing frequent freezing, boot errors, and crashes, especially when using Firefox, Chrome, or other applications. It's been quite challenging for me.
Here's some information about my system:
  Notebook: Asus Vivobook 15 M1502IA
  Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics (3000 MHz)
  RAM: 8GB
  Storage: 256GB SSD
  Kernel: 5.0.28-generic
  Ubuntu version: 23.10.1
Additionally, I should mention that this notebook fails to boot Windows; it consistently encounters BSOD during installation. I've tried Windows 11, Windows 10, Fedora, and now Ubuntu, but none seem to work smoothly. I'm starting to suspect a hardware issue, as I've had this machine for two months now and haven't been able to use it properly.
The latest error I encountered was a kernel panic with the message "not syncing fatal exception in interrupt" while attempting to boot. This happens around 10 times a day.
After some troubleshooting, I managed to get the notebook to function with the following commands added to grub:
amdgpu.gpu_recovery=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=1 processor.max_cstate=1 

rcu_nocbs=0-11
However I'm still experiencing freezing, particularly when using WhatsApp Web or when the notebook is plugged in (which it struggles to boot from). I also encountered freezing when attempting to install a game on Steam, which led me to abandon the endeavor. Despite these challenges, I was able to use the computer for over an hour today, even watching an episode of a series on Netflix and a football game via streaming.
At this point, I'm considering reaching out to ASUS official support. My suspicion is a significant hardware bug, especially given the difficulties I'm having with booting while plugged in. I'm at a loss on how to proceed and feeling quite exhausted from all the troubleshooting.
Results of neofetch :

Results of inxi -Fxzz :


https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=6230432bc4

Although no one responded here, I managed to solve the problem after a lot of headaches trying a multitude of different commands in grub, I even tried to install the new version 24.04 but it broke the system. So I used my girlfriend's notebook to create a new pen drive version 22.04 LTS with kernel 6.5.0-18generic with Rufus and so far it's running smoothly. (I haven't had the courage to update it yet) I'm downloading a game on Steam to see if it will run smoothly. If I can go 24 hours without the screen freezing I will consider it a victory.
